# iOS 5 http query with JSON object

Tags: ios, json, ios5, gis

On iOS 5, how can I query a web service using a JSON object?
I've tried a bunch of different approaches and can't get it to work.  It appears that the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) frameworks are the easiest routes, but I don't have experience with either.  I'm also new to iOS development.

Here's an example query that works:

```
https://site.com/gis?QUERY={"ARGUMENTS":{"TO":{"OBJECT_TYPE":"BUILDING","OBJECT_ID":"1","TYPE":"IDENTIFIER"},"FROM":{"OBJECT_TYPE":"BUILDING","OBJECT_ID":"2","TYPE":"IDENTIFIER"},"PATHTYPES":["SIDEWALK"},"QUERYTYPE":"FINDPATH"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a url request, see example below. This posts json data. In your case, your using a GET http method, so you shouldn't need to post the json data, you can simply include it in the url. Note that some of my variable declarations are not shown.

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"longitude", @"latitude", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:longitude, latitude, nil];

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:jsonDictionary])
{
    __jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:0 error:nil];
    __jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:__jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

// Be sure to properly escape your url string.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:@"https://site.com...etc"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: __jsonData];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [__jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  

NSError *errorReturned = nil;
NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&errorReturned];

if (errorReturned) {
    // Handle error.
}
else
{
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonParsingError];
}
```

Comment: What type of object are __jsonData and __jsonString?